# cut text from each line in a txt file

Tags: microsoft-excel, bash, regex

i have a text file where each line looks like this:

```
<img border=0 width=555 height=555 src=http://websitelinkimagelinkhere>
```

each line is like that for like 1500 lines, i want to sort of 'grep' (i dont think that will work because it returns the whole line) each line for 'http://websiteimagelinkhere'
output file should have newlines or tabs after each image link, like the original file.
or if someone only knows a way to do this with each element being in a cell of the same column that would be okay too.

Comment: There is `grep -o` that returns just the part you are looking for.

Comment: Why did you tag the question `[microsoft-excel]`? There's nothing about your question that has anything to do with that.

Comment: @dennis: i left out the word excel from the last sentence but that was what i was referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's one per line:

```
sed 's/.*src=\([^>]*\)/\1/' inputfile
```

should get it.

Are there quotes around the URL? If so:

```
sed 's/.*src="\([^"]*\)/\1/' inputfile
```

If you have GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Po '.*?src="\K.*?(?=">)' inputfile
```

Leave out the quotes if there aren't any around the URL. The `grep` version will work even if there are more than one URL on a line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Excel to put each element in its own cell, then use Data > Text to Columns….

Then use -space- as a delimiter. In your example, you'll end up with five columns in each row.